# Get cardinality possibilities from index in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, indexing, cardinality

I have a table in which a field is of variable length of specific words, and over a few thousand rows this field/index has a cardinality of about 200.

I would like to get access to that cardinality only, by which I mean the mysql response should be similar to:

```
intransitive verb
intransitive neutral verb
impersonal natural verb
impersonal phrasal verb
neuter noun
neuter plural noun
masculine noun
masculine plural noun
[etc.]
```

Thank you for your help!

(BTW English is my second language, so if you could point out better ways to express the logic that would be greatly appreciated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean there are 200 different values in this field, and you want to list them?

```
SELECT field_name FROM table GROUP BY 1
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT field_name FROM table ORDER BY 1
```

should do the trick.